# AES CTR - How can I append to CipherOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using AES/CTR/NoPadding to encrypt the downloaded files in my application. The encryption is done along with downloading. When the internet is not available in the middle of downloading, I need to pause the download and resume it when the network is available. I am using *FileOutputStream(mFile, true)* to append the rest of data to file. The issue is that I don't know how to append to *CipherOutputStream* correctly. The current implementation creates garbage data

This is my encryption method

```
private void downloadAndEncrypt() throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(mUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    long downloaded = 0;

    if(mFile.exists()){
        Logger.e("File exists. Resume Download");
        downloaded = mFile.length();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (int)downloaded + "-");
    }else{
        Logger.e("File doesn't exists. Start Download");
    }
    connection.connect();

    int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL) {
        throw new IOException("server error: " + connection.getResponseCode() + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    }

    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    if (downloaded == 0)
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    else
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile, true);

    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, mCipher);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    long total = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        total += bytesRead;
        publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
        cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    cipherOutputStream.close();
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Ciphertext is supposed to look like garbage as it is pseudo-random (it looks like random data unless you know the key, of course).

Comment: If the download completes without any interruption, everything works fine. I can access the file by decrypting. The problem comes when I resume the download (appending to file)

Comment: OK, so what happens to `mCipher` when pausing / resuming and anything in between?

Comment: The cipher is generated from key and iv stored in app itself. So there will not be any change for the cipher.

Comment: Uh, yes, but cipher instances contain *state*. Is the state interrupted?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know about the state or how to handle it

Comment: CTR mode uses a counter. Java will of course reset the counter to the IV value when you re-initialize the cipher. So you need to recalculate the IV by dividing by the number of blocks encrypted, then "encrypt" a few bytes to the precise offset. Or use a CTR mode implementation where you can explicitly indicate the offset, of course.